# html auto rowspan in while

Tags: php

i have this result of sql:

SQL:

```
+-name-+---count---+
+ cat  +  5        +
+ dog  +  6        +
+------------------+
```

count of cat is 5 and count of dog is 6.
i want to create table with auto rowspan from this result
in this code rowspan must be get count of cat and get count of dog
HTML:

```
<table>
  <th>NAME</th>
  <th>COUNT</th>
  WHILE ($sql=mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
   <tr>
      <td rowspan='$sql['cnt']'> $sql['name']; </td> 
      <td> $cnt++; </td>
   <tr>
   $cnt++;
  }
</table>
```

[image: screen shot]

Comment: you need another loop for the count

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code and images do not match, as they are reversed. Also, you are mixing php code with html.

try something like-

```
WHILE ($sql=mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
   echo '<tr>';
      echo '<td rowspan="'.$sql['count'].'" valign="center">'.$sql['name'].'</td>';
      for($i=1;$i<=$sql['count'];$i++){
      echo '<td>'.$i.'</td>';}
   echo '<tr>';
  }
```